# How do I change the comment colors in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm just trying to change the color of my comments so I can spot it faster. It's currently gray. I tried the settings but nothing that allows me to change the comment color.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts**

Uncheck *"use inherited attributes"* on the right, and it will tell you what to do.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks so much. This has been bugging me.

Comment: In 2.3 it isin File=> settings => Editor

Comment: For **Android Studio 3.4.2**: _File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Java > Comments > Line comment_. Then on the right uncheck the **Inherit values from** checkbox. Finally click the color on the right and choose the one you would like > Apply > OK.

Answer (score 5):

if you make two asterisk block comment, automatically android will turn that comment green. It's default doc comment and you don't have to change any settings.

```
/**

green comment

*/
```

Comment: superb!! that's what i was looking for to highlight specific comments!! thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In new android studio version ( Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4 ) go to -

> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Language Default

here can you customize all codes color including- **comments, classes, Number**
and etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Default is grey and green you can use green color which hightlight more than grey color.